# How to redirect javax.mail.Session setDebugOut to log4j logger?

Tags: java, email, debugging, log4j, jakarta-mail

How to redirect javax.mail.Session setDebugOut to log4j logger?

Is it possible to redirect only mailSession debug out to logger?

I mean, there are solutions like

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender/1200321#1200321)

which reassigns all standard output to go to log4j

--System.setOut(new Log4jStream())

Best Regards

Comment: Just stumbled on this old post. There is now also the option to just use a jul->slf4j bridge `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("javax.mail")` without using the PrintStream debug option.

Answer (score 13):

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) library contains useful class [LogOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/LogOutputStream.html), which you can use for this exact purpose:

```
LogOutputStream losStdOut = new LogOutputStream() {             
    @Override
    protected void processLine(String line, int level) {
        cat.debug(line);
    }
};

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null);
session.setDebugOut(new PrintStream(losStdOut));
```

cat is obviously log4j Category/Appender.

Answer (score 3):

i created an own filteroutputstream (you could also use the org.apache.logging.Logger instead of the SLF)

```
public class LogStream extends FilterOutputStream
    {
        private static org.slf4j.Logger             LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogStream.class);
        private static final OutputStream   bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        public LogStream(OutputStream out)
            {
                // initialize parent with my bytearray (which was never used)
                super(bos);
            }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException
            {
                // this was never called in my test
                bos.flush();
                if (bos.size() > 0) LOG.info(bos.toString());
                bos.reset();
            }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException
            {
                LOG.info(new String(b));
            }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
            {
                LOG.info(new String(b, off, len));
            }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException
            {
                write(new byte[] { (byte) b });
            }
    }
```

then i redirected the javamail to my output

```
// redirect the output to our logstream
javax.mail.Session def = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
def.setDebugOut(new PrintStream(new LogStream(null)));
def.setDebug(true);
```

that did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Write your own OutputStream class

and

mailSession.setDebugOut(new PrintStream(your custom aoutput stream object));