# logging stderr and stdout with log4j

Tags: java, log4j, logging

Following the receipt on 
[log4j redirect stdout to DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender)

And it was working until some point, and then it stopped working for some unknown reason.

Any idea of what can be wrong? i verified and im running exactly the same code as tieSystemOutAndErrToLog.

My log4j.properties is:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, rollingFile, CONSOLE

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
log4j.logger.com.mchange=INFO
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony=WARN
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl=ERROR

log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, rollingFile
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false

#log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool=INFO


log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=/export/log/alpha/frontend.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %p %t %c - %m%n
```

in particular, im not able to log this event that is logged in catalina.out:

```
Dec 10, 2010 1:40:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
so i finally figured this out. for some obscure reason that i cannot even fathom, tomcat is not routing uncaught exceptions through log4j, and they are dumped to stdout, i had to log them in an exception page..

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you reference a JAR file that contains its own log4j.property?

Comment: nope. i see things being logged to /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out but nothing in /export/log/alpha/frontend.log. And as i mentioned it was working great before.. not sure what happened..

Comment: Does the fact that there is logging in catalina.out really mean that you are might not be picking up another log4j.properties file, as suggested?

Comment: no, i dont have other properties file. Besides, catalina.out is a default escape for loggging, i.e. log4j is missing these events for some reason i cannot comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "-Dlog4j.debug" to see which log4j file you're using

Comment: i know which log4j file im using , but these events are not being captured by the logger..

Answer (score 0):

No permissions (of the Tomcat process owner) to write into target log file? :)