# Print System.out.println in log file of Apache Karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I have an OSGi Jar file which I am deploying on Apache Karaf. The underlining code has system.out.println statements but I am not able to view them in the Apache Karaf log file. I see that my bundle is active.

Is there any property which I can set to enable it?

I am new to OSGi and Karaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log4j logging configuration is placed in {karaf.home}/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg file.

You should prepare configuration like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5743102/5898010

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

The log file only contains what you sent through one of the logging APIs. Karaf uses [pax-logging](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxlogging/Documentation). So the logging APIs available are log4j, sl4fj,  commons logging and some others.

Anything sent to System.out will go to the local console but not the log.