# Redirect sysout & syserr output(console) to log file in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, redirect, tomcat7, log-files

I want to redirect my sysout or syserr console output to log file in tomcat7

Comment: Try this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer your exact question but hope it helps....

To print output generated by command prompt to a file use the following

Ex:

```
jar tvf apache-cassandra-1.0.8.jar > out
```

The output will be stored in a file called out in the same directory