# log4j not printing jdbctemplate logs

Tags: logging, log4j, jdbctemplate, jboss-eap-6

I have following configuration.If i make change to it the existing application debug logs stop coming.I have tried to make changes to enable

1. system.out.pritlln,
2. jdbc template logs
3. spring security logs

but they are not coming.What changes can i do make the logs enable.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, stderr
log4j.category.com.de.bridge=DEBUG, SYSLOG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log


log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to syslogd
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{2} %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=LOCAL1
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Threshold=info
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.FacilityPrinting=true
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core = TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG, file
log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE, file
```

I have my jboss-deployment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Log4j was changed as below
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=trace, file,CONSOLE

```
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=DEBUG,file
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils=TRACE, file
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG, file
log4j.category.org.springframework.security=DEBUG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/log1.log


log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

web.xml was changed as below

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[log4j redirect stdout to DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender) was used to send the system.out.println to the log file.
I added the static block in one of my startup servlet to call the class

```
public class SSOLogin extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SSOLogin.class.getName());


 static
        {
            StdOutErrLog.tieSystemOutAndErrToLog();
        }
```

Commented the exclusion in deployment file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
      <deployment>
        <exclusions>
    <!--         <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" /> -->
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

..........................