# Log events from com.sun.mail which use PrintStream with log4j into separate file

Tags: java, email, logging, log4j

com.sun.* package use PrintStream for logging. For example class *com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport*

```
private PrintStream out;
...
if (debug)
        out.println("DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo " + useEhlo + ", useAuth " + useAuth);
```

is this possible to log these events with log4j? One solution, is to create proxy for System output, like here is suggested: [log4j redirect stdout to DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender), but problem is, there would be logged all events which use PrintStream, not only com.sun.mail.* package, and I can't only log from com.sun.* package.

For example I want to log email events into separate file, but can't, because of probability of some other class from some 3rd party library using PrintStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaMail 1.4.7 or newer uses the [JDK logging](http://javamail.java.net/docs/CHANGES.txt) along with the legacy support for the printstream. The [Log4j JUL Adapter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-jul/index.html) can be used to capture output from JavaMail.  The [JavaMail API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) documents the names of the JDK loggers at the bottom of each JavaMail package.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MAIL.File=/path/to/MAIL.log
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.logger.com.sun.mail=LEVEL, MAIL
```

Append new MAIL appeender to root logger

```
log4j.rootLogger= ... , MAIL
```

Comment: I've tried like this, and this doens't work, as I understood, because of SMTPTransport class not using logger, but using PrintStream to log their events