# How to set the DB Credentials of log4j at runtime

Tags: java, logging, log4j

This is my log4j properties file. I'm writing logs into db. I want to set the db credentials at run time

```
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.0.201:1433;databaseName=databaseone;autoReconnect=true
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
log4j.appender.DB.user=username
log4j.appender.DB.password=password$123
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO usage_fact(accessed_date,accessed_item_id,user_id,tenant_id,log_level) VALUES('%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%X{accessed_item_id}','%X{user_id}','%X{tenant_id}','%p')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

And how do i catch the sql exception arises while log4j connecting to db or writing into table. all exception stack trace are printing on console i don't want to print this on console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize the logging framework through java code like this:

```
public class CoreLogger {
    public static Logger getLogger(final Class moduleName) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(moduleName);
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(new FileReader("log4j.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        prop.put("log4j.appender.DB.user", "root");
        prop.put("log4j.appender.DB.password", "root");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
        return logger;
    }
}
```

and use

```
static Logger log = CoreLogger.getLogger(Demo.class);
```

In your classes to get the instance of logger, this way you can set the credentials at run time.

Regarding capturing errors in files, you can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to your log files refer `Dario's` answer at [log4j redirect stdout to DailyRollingFileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200175/log4j-redirect-stdout-to-dailyrollingfileappender) for more details about that.

Comment: Run time properties changing is working fine, But before that log4j trying to connect to data base its printing sql exception on my tomcat console. how to make log4j internal logs not to print on console

Comment: For that you can refer the link I have provided in the answer.